# Optimizing a master/detail MySQL query with or without INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

MySQL is not my specific field of expertise, and since I never needed to handle big tables, my basic knowledge has been enough - until now :)

When I have a master/detail MySQL tables, I always do queries like this:

```
SELECT SUM(detail.qty)
FROM master, detail
WHERE master.id = detail.masterId
  AND (interestingField = interestingValue)
```

But right now, I have too may details rows and so the query is slow. I tried to understand the "INNER" syntax, and I came up with

```
SELECT SUM(detail.qty)
FROM master 
INNER JOIN detail ON master.id = detail.masterId
WHERE (interestingField = interestingValue)
```

but the timing is still the same... So:

1) Does it mean that doing INNER JOIN is THE SAME than checking the master/detail field by hand?

2) Apart from making indexes using the required fields (which I already did), is there a way to make the query faster?

Thank you and sorry if the question seems dumb :(

----- As requested, I am adding the EXPLAIN output to my query

```
     +----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  |  type  | possible_keys |     key     | key_len | ref  |              rows               | Extra |             |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|    |           1 | SIMPLE | bill_t | ALL           | PRIMARY,id  | NULL    | NULL | NULL                            |  4441 | Using where |
|    |           1 | SIMPLE | bill_d | ref           | billId,type | billId  | 5    | localtha_bg3667772802.bill_t.id |     2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Please use `Explain Analyze`. From that execute plan we can see why your query are slow..

Comment: if I use EXPLAIN myquery it gives me 2 rows as a result (I will edit my question with it), but if I do ANALYZE myquery it gives me error. It gives me an error also if I type EXPLAIN ANALYZE myquery (sorry, never used those commands :)

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` won't be any faster than `WHERE` since the query optimizer should produce an identical execution plan for both queries provided. However, different DB engines might produce different execution plans but typically such behaviour is observed for more complex queries (which this is not the case here). I would suggest to test both queries and choose the one which is faster.

As a general advice, I would recommend `INNER JOIN` which IMO is much more readable and it reduces the risk of omitting the condition in the `WHERE` clause that might lead to a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you. Running BOTH queries ("where" and "inner join" versions) with 1000 different parameters produce the same results. I will then start using the INNER JOIN version even though for me it's harder to read :)

Answer (score 0):

for your query with master and detail performance assuming that interestingField in detail table  be sure  you have a proper composite index  on

```
    create index  idx1 on detail (interestingField, masterId )
```

For the INNER JOIN and Where  the implicit join based  on where is an OLD way for manage join  .. the recente version is based on Explictic JOIN condition eg:

```
  SELECT SUM(detail.qty)
  FROM master 
  INNER  detail ON master.id = detail.masterId
      AND interestingField = interestingValue
```

each the way are the same for performance

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Regarding the "sum", unfortunately I cannot do that (or I am doing it wrong...) because I need to sum the value ONLY if some field of the MASTER has a specific value, in this case a date field.

Comment: @ZioBit   .. OK  .. part for sum deleted  ..  answer  updated ..eventually add a proper data sample and the expected  result  .. the condtion `interestingField = interestingValue ` is ambigous   and could be you need  more columns in index ..

Comment: you are right, I just do not want to make this specific to my problem. The master table has 16 fields, the details has 14, and in the where clause I check for 6 of them so... I guess it will be too specific, I do not want ppl complain that I was looking for a single solution to my specific problem :) I just wanted an advice on "if" the inner join was the same than m.id=d.id (it is!) and if I was making something wrong (it doesn't look like). Thank you for the explanation!